# Steam Link messes up DHCP

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, draytek

Yes, this title is a little bit weird, but bear with me. I've been at this for more than a week and I'm kind of dumping all information I've been able to collect here in hopes of someone being able to help me out.

When I'm talking about my "modem" I'm probably referring to router functionality, but my ISP calls it a modem. I have a wall mounted thing where the fiber connection enters my house, and then the "modem" which is connected to that.

---

### What happened before

About 9 days ago I switched ISP, who installed a Draytek Vigor 2132F fiber modem. After a few days my internet over LAN suddenly quit working, while it kept working over WiFi.

Called my ISP, they reset my modem and it worked for about 2 days. Then internet over LAN specifically stopped working again. My ISP sent someone over and they replaced the modem. A few hours later, once again no internet over LAN.

### Current situation

Now I'm 9 days in and I haven't been able to get proper internet over LAN. After troubleshooting with some people over 2 different forums I'm pretty sure I've narrowed it down to the Steam Link being the problem.

*(The Steam Link is a small device by Valve you connect to your TV by HDMI. You can then stream your PC to your TV and connect pretty much any controller to the Link, perfect for gaming with friends and streaming movies, see: http://store.steampowered.com/app/353380/Steam_Link/)*

### My amateur guess

There's a problem with DHCP, when the internet over LAN fails I suddenly have an IP outside of my subnet range. My subnet is 255.255.255.0 with the IP's being 192.168.1.x. When it fails I suddenly get a subnet of 255.255.0.0 and an IP being 192.168.(169/72/etc).x. I tried setting a fixed IP on my LAN adapter, disabling IPv6, letting my modem hand out a fixed IP to my PC through MAC address, etc. but none of that worked. I couldn't even get a connection with my modem unless I rebooted it.

Someone said, there's probably some device on your network that is handing out IPs through DHCP which is messing with the DHCP of your modem. This seems to be my Steam Link.

Just now my internet had been working again for 3 hours (as it always temporarily does after a modem reboot) and I started up my Steam Link to watch a movie. I get to my desktop and boom, no internet.

Is there any way to disable to DHCP server of the Steam Link so that it only receives an IP and doesn't hand out IPs? Not only that, this used to work perfectly with my previous ISP.

### The setup

LAN 1 and 2 are meant for internet, LAN 3 and 4 are configured for TV, set up like that by my ISP. I've been told bridge mode wouldn't work and I shouldn't but DD-WRT or OpenWRT on it.

My current set up is:

```
Windows 10 PC --> LAN 1 |
Steam Link -----> LAN 2 |---> Draytek 2132F ---> Fiber connection
TV -------------> LAN 3 |
                        |
iPhone 7 ~~~~~~~> WLAN  |
```

What I've just tried in hopes of fixing it is giving my Steam link a static IP, hoping that that prevents it from trying to deal out an IP to my PC outside of my modem's range.

Sadly I don't have enough reputation yet to create the new "steam-link" tag.

---

## Update

After troubleshooting a load with [some people on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam_Link/comments/7aqx4f/steam_link_crashes_my_modem/) it seems that DHCP and routing just crashes on my Draytek modem. Probably because some sort of traffic between my PC and the Steam Link. I've put a router with dd-wrt between it all and am hoping that that will prevent further problems.

Comment: So everything is plugged directly into the Draytek? there are no other devices connected?

Comment: There were none but I've now placed a router behind the modem. I added a small update at the bottom of my question right before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with some people on Reddit I've decided to go for the only solution that I can possibly think of: Just putting my own router behind the modem.

I can't use Bridge mode according to my ISP so I guess I'll just have to live with two devices doing NAT. It's been working flawlessly for a few weeks now.

I've reported it to my ISP and sent them all my technical data, but I doubt they will even look at it.